# How can i convert the complex infinte series into a integral?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I tried to convert this infinite sum into an defined integral, for easier caluclations. The Problem i don't have much experience with sums or even the Riemann sum. I tried my best to solve it, but i couldn't find a resource that describes hvo you convert a complex function into an integral.

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{k}(-1)^{n-1}\cdot n^{-x}\cdot n^{-iy}$$

My try is this integral, which only works when $x = 1$:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}*n^{-iy} dn \Leftarrow x = 1$$
But i'm very sure that this is wrong

Any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: This is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function). It has a well-known integral representation.

Comment: Use $$\frac{1}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-n t} t^{s-1}\mathrm{d}t.$$